# Assistance with regex text extraction

Tags: regex

I am struggling to extract the text in between the `|207| xxxxxxx |4|` in the line below:

```
|DCIP|2.8.1|207|Anomalous File/EXE from Rare External Location|4|externalId=28906
```

The 207 and 4 could be any number.

I am new to regex and slowing getting grips. Any pointers would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `\|\d+\|` to match digits surrounded by `|`.
- Use capturing group to extract that part out later.

```js
var text = '|DCIP|2.8.1|207|Anomalous File/EXE from Rare External ..|4|ext..';
var matched = text.match(/\|\d+\|([^|]+)\|\d+\|/)[1];
console.log(matched);
```

Comment: Thanks - almost too easy. That statement selects includes the number. How would you just eaxtract the text between the |207| and |4|.

Comment: @DamianJ, Did you run the code? It prints the text inbetween, not `|207|` nor `|4|`.

Comment: @DamianJ, Here I used `text.match(/.../)[1]` to extract the captured group. The way to extract the group is different between languages. You should give more information about the language/tool/regex-engine you're using.

Comment: Soz should have done that first. Now run the code and it looks good. The only thing I have now noticed is that if the first section has less than 3 digits it throws the output off. See xample below:

Comment: @DamianJ, What example? I cannot see any example.

Comment: Soz should have done that first. Now run the code and it looks good. The only thing I have now noticed is that if the first section has less than 3 digits it throws the output off. See example : "|53|Compliance/Remote Management Tool On Server|3|" returns "Compliance/Remote M6 src=ent Tool On Server" so I change the statement to \|\d{1,3}+\|([^|]+)\|\d+\| which works for the main but I have the odd one that does not seem to play ball, for example "|53|Compliance/Remote Management Tool On Server|3|" returns Compliance/Remote M7 src=ent Tool On Server

Comment: @DamianJ, You have extra `+` in `\d{1,3}+`. It should be just `\d{1,3}`.  `"|53|Compliance/Remote Management Tool On Server|3|".match(/\|\d{1,3}\|([^|]+)\|\d+\|/)[1]`